# How to tell what Safari tab requires high performance GPU?

Tags: macos, safari, performance, gpu

I'm experiencing lower than expected battery life on my 2015 Macbook Pro. I believe that part of the problem is that the High Performance GPU is being activated when not needed by some tab in Safari:
[image: Activity Monitor Energy Pane]

This is NOT a CPU related problem, as the CPU tab in Activity Monitor shows little activity:
[image: Activity Monitor CPU pane]

How can I tell which tab is requiring the high-performance GPU?

### [Update]

After closing *all* tabs, Safari is still requiring the high-performance GPU.

Comment: Close each tab in turn, watch for changes.

Comment: @SolarMike yes, that is an option, but I use the tabs to remind me of what I need to go back and review.  I'd prefer to not have to close them.

Comment: So bookmark them...

Comment: Surely there must be a more definitive way.

Comment: There may be, but how long are you prepared to suffer / wait or do you want to find out sooner?

Comment: @SolarMike all tabs closed, not a single Safari window open (although the app is open).  Still uses High Perf GPU.

Comment: Fixed https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14469/determine-cpu-usage-in-safari-tab

Comment: @DarwinOSX if I read that thread correctly, they are talking about CPU usage. I need to know about the high-performance (as opposed to integrated) GPU.  This is the *Graphics* Processing Unit, not the *Central* Processing Unit.